# Change element from main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

On my https://getsatisfaction.com/gsfnmichelle/products page, there's a bread crumb trail that says "Products." I'm trying to change that to "Categories." I can get it to do that within the inspector, but when I put the code in the customization script (which is only the main page /gsfnmichelle on the platform I'm using), it doesn't work.

Even though I was able to get the correct element (jQuery('.crumb_link span');) and change it using ( jQuery('.crumb_link span').text('Categories');), I can't figure out how to change it when it's within another page (/products) besides the main one (/gsfnmichelle), since it's the only place where we can insert customization code.

I thought something like this would check for the page and change that element, but it doesn't work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.pathname =="/gsfnmichelle/products") {
        jQuery('.crumb_link span').text('Categories');}
};
```

Then I tried to use an if statement to check for the right element, but that doesn't work either:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if (jQuery('.crumb_link span').text =='Products') { 
        jQuery('.crumb_link span').text('Categories');}
};
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use either `if (jQuery('.crumb_link span').text() == "Products")` or `jQuery('.crumb_link span:contains(Products)').text('Categories')`.

Your current condition will never be true.